# How to make a query using "where MONTH(datetime)" faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, datetime

I already tried to add an index on the `datetime` column, but the result is still unacceptably slow.

```
SELECT s.id, s.player,
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totalwin, 
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totallose, 
COUNT(dg.winner) as totalgames 
       FROM dotaplayers AS dp 
       LEFT JOIN gameplayers AS gp ON gp.gameid = dp.gameid and dp.colour = gp.colour 
       LEFT JOIN stats AS s ON s.player_lower = gp.name 
       LEFT JOIN dotagames AS dg ON dg.gameid = dp.gameid 
       LEFT JOIN games AS g ON g.id = dp.gameid 
       LEFT JOIN bans as b ON b.name=gp.name
       WHERE MONTH(g.datetime) = 4
       GROUP by gp.name
       ORDER BY totalwin DESC LIMIT 0,10

Showing rows 0 - 9 (10 total, Query took 7.7552 seconds.)
```

If someone wants to help, I can provide a copy of my database, it is only 120 MB in size.

Comment: Has `g.datetime` an index? Can you post your `CREATE TABLE` script?

Comment: @oNare in create table, g.datetime not index, but when im creating this query. im add index to that table using phpmyadmin...

Comment: It doesn't matter if you create an index in phpmyadmin, the index must be in  `g.datetime` if you want to decrease the time. Try it.

Comment: @oNare im sure the datetime already index, http://prntscr.com/7qe4mc

Answer (score 2):

Using the MONTH() function on a column automatically disqualifies any index from usage

You can state the range in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT s.id, s.player,
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totalwin, 
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totallose, 
COUNT(dg.winner) as totalgames 
       FROM dotaplayers AS dp 
       LEFT JOIN gameplayers AS gp ON gp.gameid = dp.gameid and dp.colour = gp.colour 
       LEFT JOIN stats AS s ON s.player_lower = gp.name 
       LEFT JOIN dotagames AS dg ON dg.gameid = dp.gameid 
       LEFT JOIN games AS g ON g.id = dp.gameid 
       LEFT JOIN bans as b ON b.name=gp.name
       WHERE g.datetime >= '2015-04-01 00:00:00'
       AND   g.datetime <  '2015-05-01 00:00:00'
       GROUP by gp.name
       ORDER BY totalwin DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

or move  the range from the `WHERE` to the `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT s.id, s.player,
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totalwin, 
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totallose, 
COUNT(dg.winner) as totalgames 
       FROM dotaplayers AS dp 
       LEFT JOIN gameplayers AS gp ON gp.gameid = dp.gameid and dp.colour = gp.colour 
       LEFT JOIN stats AS s ON s.player_lower = gp.name 
       LEFT JOIN dotagames AS dg ON dg.gameid = dp.gameid 
       LEFT JOIN games AS g ON g.id = dp.gameid AND g.datetime>='2015-04-01 00:00:00' AND g.datetime<'2015-05-01 00:00:00'
       LEFT JOIN bans as b ON b.name=gp.name
       GROUP by gp.name
       ORDER BY totalwin DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

## UPDATE 2015-07-08 15:19 EST

Try using `INNER JOIN` on `games` since you need a specific month

```
SELECT s.id, s.player,
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totalwin, 
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totallose, 
COUNT(dg.winner) as totalgames 
       FROM dotaplayers AS dp 
       LEFT JOIN gameplayers AS gp ON gp.gameid = dp.gameid and dp.colour = gp.colour 
       LEFT JOIN stats AS s ON s.player_lower = gp.name 
       LEFT JOIN dotagames AS dg ON dg.gameid = dp.gameid 
       INNER JOIN games AS g ON g.id = dp.gameid 
       LEFT JOIN bans as b ON b.name=gp.name
       WHERE g.datetime >= '2015-04-01 00:00:00'
       AND   g.datetime <  '2015-05-01 00:00:00'
       GROUP by gp.name
       ORDER BY totalwin DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: first, its same -> Query took 8.0019 seconds. The second the result isnt correct and its took more longer, Query took 30.4748 seconds.

Comment: You could add a trigger and use it to add data (an INTEGER) to a game_month column, which you could then index?

Comment: @Vérace Good point. You would have to index on year and month otherwise, you could retrieve the same month over several years.

Comment: Good point - but the OP's query just has a month of 4 - no year (probably an oversight).

Comment: Easier to write: `g.datetime >= '2015-04-01' AND g.datetime < '2015-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`